# Change in property on collapse of panel after drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Thank you Am working on a accordion menu which are created dynamically on button click and it is also and nested accordion. and am performing drag and drop. when am click and dragging a particular panel and dropped  its panel body where the panel contents are available are overlapped by other panels in the field.

### achieve or issues solved

1.success in swapping of two panels.

### Unsolved issues

1.overlapping of other panels in the field(work space).

screenshot 1 click create test

I have attached my screenshots of my issues

[image: This is my issue]

Please click on the number below the picture from 6 to 1 to view the screenshots

Comment: Please don't post too many screenshots on one question. Instead, show a demo of the problem. I also don't really understand the structure of the screenshots.

Comment: Also, in your JSFiddle, please don't include 3 of the same dependencies.

Comment: ok sir will edit the jsfiddle now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7mgkwfcg/7/